# How to add CKEditor to Sonata Admin backend's textareas

Tags: symfony, textarea, ckeditor, sonata-admin

I'd like to add CKEditor to the Sonata Admin backend. For now I only have Create Bundle running, which allows me to edit the content inline, but I'd like to use an editor in the backend too. I tried Formatter Widget, but it is a little oversized, since I do not want to create new fields in my entities.

Has anyone done this already?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution of zizoujab was totally correct, so I upvoted it. But, as my question refered to SonataAdminBundle, there need to be done a little more. That's why I give this additional answer.

I solved this by overriding the `SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig` in a custom bundle:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script src="{{ asset('js/ckeditor/adapter/jquery.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('textarea.ckeditor').ckeditor();
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Also I had the problem, that this didn't work because of the version of ckeditor I used. I was not able to use the one, CmfCreateBundle installs. This generated some js errors and the `<textarea>` tag vanished.
So I had to download the "standard" version from ckeditor.com, which worked.

Comment: To use the ckeditor.js shipped with CmfCreate  you just need to set the `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` variable before including it, tike this: `<script>window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '{{ app.request.basePath }}/bundles/cmfcreate/vendor/ckeditor/';</script><script src="{{ asset('js/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>`

Answer (score 8):

Include ckeditor script in your page and add `ckeditor`  class to your textarea, that's all.

Example : In your form type :

```
$builder->add('description', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor')))
```

and in your twig :

```
   <script src="{{ asset('js/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
     .
     .
     .
    {{form(form)}}
```

Comment: I tried this by extending the SonataAdminBundle and creating a CRUD/edit.html.twig with the following lines:
    `{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}

    {% block javascripts %}
     {{ parent() }}
     <script src="{{ asset('js/ckeditor_ckeditor_1.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}`

Now the ckeditor.js is correctly included from web/js and the textarea tag has class 'ckeditor'.

But the textarea field is not getting rendered at all. Is there any configuration of SonataAdminBundle, that prevents this from happening?

Comment: This is the generated code for my textarea field:
`<div class="controls sonata-ba-field sonata-ba-field-standard-natural  ">

                <textarea id="s52c4390577ec2_text1" name="s52c4390577ec2[text1]"    class="ckeditor"></textarea>

                
                            </div>`

Comment: btw I'm getting the same result with IvoryCKEditorBundle

Comment: what happen when you execute this script in your javascript console ?   `CKEDITOR.replaceAll()`

Comment: What you wrote was correct, the problem mainly was the version of my ckeditor and the overriding of the SonataAdminBundle:CRUD template. But your answer was very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want some WYSIWYG editor, and it is possible to use NOT CKEditor, - then I'll suggest to look a [sonata-formatter-bundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/master/doc/reference/installation.html)

Comment: I wrote in my question, that I do not want to use the formatter widget. Is what you suggest possible without that widget? Your suggestion confuses me.

Comment: sorry, i've missed it in question. If you do not what to create an additional fields, even virtual, than i'll suggest to use sollution provided by enigma bellow.

Answer (score 4):

Following the [updated doc](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataFormatterBundle/tree/master/Resources/doc/reference) for **[Sonata Formatter](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataFormatterBundle)**

***config.yml:***

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

    # These 3 lines below were missing in my own conf
    # Adding them made formatter richtext editor alternatives
    # finally available in my project:

    form:
        resources:
            - 'SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig'
```

***sonata.yml***

```
sonata_block:
    (...)
    blocks:
        (...)
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.page.block.children_pages:
        sonata.formatter.block.formatter:
(...)
sonata_formatter:
    formatters:
        markdown:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.markdown
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig

        text:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.text
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig

        rawhtml:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig

        richhtml:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig

        twig:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.twigengine
            extensions: [] # Twig formatter cannot have extensions

    ckeditor:
        templates:
            browser: 'SonataFormatterBundle:Ckeditor:browser.html.twig'
            upload: 'SonataFormatterBundle:Ckeditor:upload.html.twig'
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason the ckeditor block is not on the same tabs as the other formatters and it was giving me an error that the "template" property is unknown. Putting ckeditor on the same level as formatters fixed this issue! :)